# I want a regex pattern to grab text within a pattern that excludes matches followed by a particular string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm using preg_match_all() like this:

```
preg_match_all('/("user":"(.*?)".*?-->)/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

On a string, the idea is that I want it to get whatever comes after "user" in a commented out block (it's a long story). So let's say $input_lines is something like:

```
<!-- block {"user":"josh-hart", 1234566 ,"hide":false} /-->
<!-- block {"user":"jalen-brunson", 7744633 ,"hide":true} /-->
<!-- block {"user":"julius-randle", 333333,"hide":false} /-->
<!-- block {"user":"obi-toppin", 4hh3n33n33n, /-->
<!-- block {"user":"rj-barrett", nmremxxx!! ,"hide":true} /-->
<!-- block {"user":"mitch-robinson",yahaoao /-->
```

I want it to match the user. But here's the the thing, I only want the user if `"hide":true` does not appear before the `/-->`. So for this string I would want the matches to be:

```
josh-hart, julius-randle, obi-toppin, mitch-robinson
```

What is this called in regex terms and how do i do it?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "lookahead", https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Here's an example: [`"user":"([^"]*?)"(?!(?:(?!\/-->).)*"hide"\s*:\s*true)`](https://regex101.com/r/BuF2Dk/1)

Comment: You can also use [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to skip something. Further [`\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) Something like e.g. [`"user":"\K[^"]+(?:[^>]*?"hide":true(*SKIP)(*F))?`](https://regex101.com/r/Q0wGeS/1) might suffice for your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that opening and closing a comment is from `<!--` to `-->` and there is no other use of these in between, you can first get the matches out of the way that contain `<!-- ... "hide":true ... -->` without crossing the opening or closing of a comment.

Then you can get a single match of the username, still in between the comment markers and independent of the order of appearance.

```
<!--(?:(?!-->|"hide":).)*+"hide":true\b(?:(?!-->).)*/-->(*SKIP)(*F)|<!--(?:(?!-->|"user":).)*"user":"\K[^"]+(?="(?:(?!-->).)*-->)
```

The pattern matches:

- `<!--` Match literaly
- `(?:(?!-->|"hide":).)*+` Optionally repeat matching any character not directly followed by either `-->` or `"hide":` using a [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)
- `"hide":true\b` Match `"hide":true` followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:(?!-->).)*/-->` Match until the closing `-->`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the current match
- `|` Or
- `<!--` Match literally
- `(?:(?!-->|"user").)*` Optionally repeat matching any character not directly followed by either `-->` or `"user:`
- `"user":"\K` Match `"user":"` and forget what is matched so far
- `[^"]+` Match 1+ chars other than `"` (the username that you want to match)
- `(?="(?:(?!-->).)*-->)` Assert `-->` to the right

**Note** that you can make the matching of the username more specific, as for now it matches 1 or more characters other than a double quote with `[^"]+`  which can also be a space or a newline. If you want to match only non whitespace characters except for a double quote, than you can change it to `[^\s"]+`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9btrqh/1).

Answer (score 2):

You may try that:

```
user":"([^"]+)"(?!.*"hide":true(?=.*\/-->))
```

Explanation:

- `user":"([^"]+)"` - after matching  `user":"` it looks for characters inside `"` until it reaches a `"`.
- `()` ensures 1st capture group.
- `(?!.*"hide":true` negative lookahead to figure there is no
  `"hide":true` after that.
- `(?=.*\/-->)` positive lookahead to ensure that `/-->` is not preceded by `"hide":true`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmLOn4/1)

Answer (score 2):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76520368#comment134920546_76520368) by @bobblebubble, you can use the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` combo to skip whatever you don't want to match:

```
^                     # Match at the start of a line
.*                    # anything
"hide"\s*:\s*true     # followed by '"hide":true'
.*                    # then anything until the end of the line
                      # (i.e. a line that contains '"hide":true')
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)        # which we tell the engine to skip entirely
|                     # or
"user"\s*:\s*"\K      # '"user":"', which we forfeit,
[^"]+                 # followed by 1 or more non-quote characters.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Gsg9J9/1).